# How to replicate mysql range and limit in SQL Server using the top clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've been trying to replicate the limit and range feature provided in MySql in SQL Server with no luck as of yet. I have found several guides and now think my sql code is nearly correct but I'm still getting an error posted below.

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
>   Only one expression can be specified
>   in the select list when the subquery
>   is not introduced with EXISTS

The error code says to use EXISTS but i have tried that instead of NOT IN and i still get an error.

My sql is posted below

```
SELECT TOP (@range) * 
FROM client 
WHERE clientId NOT IN 
      (SELECT TOP (@limit) * 
       FROM client 
       ORDER BY clientId) 
ORDER BY clientId
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The change you need to make to your code is

```
SELECT TOP (@range) *
FROM   client
WHERE  clientId NOT IN (SELECT TOP (@limit) clientId /*<-- NOT "*" here */
                        FROM   client
                        ORDER  BY clientId)
ORDER  BY clientId
```

This can also be done by using `row_number` as below (which performs better depends on the different indexes available and how wide a covering index on the whole query is compared to a narrow one on just `clientId`.)

```
DECLARE @lowerlimit int
SET @lowerlimit = @range +@limit;

WITH cte As
(
SELECT TOP (@lowerlimit) * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY clientId) AS RN
FROM client
ORDER BY clientId
)
SELECT * /*TODO: Your Actual column list*/
FROM cte 
WHERE RN >= @limit
```

Comment: Thanks that works. I wasn't as close to correct answer as i thought then.

Comment: +1 for the windows function. IT's has only one scan so almost always will perform better (unless the optimizer does one of his magic tricks)

Comment: @andrew - You were pretty close and you may want to try both alternatives and look at the costs to see which is best for your data.

Answer (score 0):

Another (similar, slower :) ) way

```
SELECT * FROM (       
    select rank() over (ORDER BY yourorder) as rank, *.X
                from TableX X
) x2 WHERE rank between 5 and 10
```